# Lion installation gets stuck after reboot at Apple logo

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I have a 2006 Macbook Pro with Snow Leopard as the OS X and I recently purchased OS X 10.7 from the App Store.  After download, I began the installation of Lion, it restarted and just remained at the grayish window with the black apple and the black pinwheel.  I left it alone, but after hours, just remained there, no progress

Comment: Start in Single user mode to see what is happening line by line. http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492

Comment: I'd recommend verbose mode instead as the actual boot procedure will be unaffected. —cc @Buscar

Comment: try creating the installer using a USB: *https://www.lifewire.com/create-bootable-flash-drive-os-x-lion-installer-2260350*

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things you can do (short of reinstalling the OS)

- Start in [Verbose mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492) (cc George)
- Start with <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd> using the disk utility to repair disk permissions
- Start in Safe mode (hold Shift)  to see if non OS apps are doing that.
- Reset your [SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964)